# Views block showing empty content on front end

Tags: 7, views, theming, blocks

I created a view to show a list of news items. I placed the view block in the content bottom region of the page. In the Views preview, it shows the results. However in the front end, the content is empty and shows:

```
<div id="block-views-news_list-block_1" class="clear-block block block-views">
<div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

I do have a view template for this block - views-view--news-list--block-1.tpl.php. In the Views page it shows this template as selected. I do not see that it is being rendered on the page though. Even when I just put a basic div with text in the views template, nothing shows in the content div.

What are the possible reasons for this? What can I do to get content to show?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was my theme's block.tpl.php file. It was displaying content like so, `$block->content`.

I changed it to match the block.tpl.php file in modules/block:

```
<?php print $content ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

I would check the following:

Does it work without the views template?

Does it use arguments in the view? If so, are they set correctly in the block.